# Importa Banco SQLite Pré-existente usando o Expo-Sqlite

Tags: banco-de-dados, react-native, sqlite, expo

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação offline firts com Expo do react-native, porem eu queria ter o acesso ao banco que o SQLite cria através de uma interface para poder fazer algumas manipulações e verificações. Segui a documentação do ExpoSQlite mas sem sucesso. Queria entender melhor como posso fazer isso usando o expo_file_System. Minha ideia é criar o banco por fora e jogar dentro da raiz do projeto. Minha pergunta é como isso pode ser feito sendo que o OpenDataBase só aceita o nome do Banco e não um caminho especifico ?

```
 import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
 import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';

const reabilitaCovidDB = openDatabase();

async function openDatabase(pathToDatabaseFile) {
  if (!(await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 
 'SQLite')).exists) {
  await FileSystem.makeDirectoryAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite');
 }
 await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
  Asset.fromModule(require(pathToDatabaseFile)).uri,
  FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'SQLite/myDatabaseName.db'
 );
 return SQLite.openDatabase('MEU_BANCO_NA_RAIZ.db');
}

export default reabilitaCovidDB
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Poderia colocar o código de maneira textual na pergunta?

Comment: @Danizavtz fiz a alteração